# How can I get Policykit-1-KDE to preselect the current user?

Tags: 11.10, 12.04, kubuntu, users, policykit

On my new Kubuntu 11.10 system, there are two users with administrative rights (`paulo` and `administranto`). Whenever I now from a KDE GUI dialog do some action which needs administrative rights, I get a dialog like the one showing below, asking me to select a user and type the password. I can't start typing the password before I select the user name, and I need to use the mouse (or some combination of arrow-down, back-tab, arrow-down) to select the right user from the list.

I'm just now logged in as `paulo` - how can I configure it to preselect the current user and focus the password box right away?

[image: screenshot]

(Yes, this screen shot has a strange mix of Esperanto and German. Looks like the Esperanto translation is not yet complete.)

A workaround would be to remove the administrator rights from the second user, but this is not what I want, really.

*(This still happens on 12.04, but I just filed a [bug report/feature request](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/polkit-kde-1/+bug/1010632).)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what I have seen this would need to coding in the source for it. I recommend filing a report about this so they can added in a new release. The workaround you mention would work since there would be only one but like you just said, an preselected option should be available when multiple users exist, at least to save up on time from selecting the user (or previous user if it was selected earlier).

Comment: Thanks for the note - I now filed [bug 1010632 at launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/polkit-kde-1/+bug/1010632).